# What is my AHB1 clock rate?

Tags: embedded, arm, clock-speed

I am working with an ARM Cortex M3 chip (reference manual available [here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/REFERENCE_MANUAL/CD00225773.pdf)). I'm trying to get the baud rate of my USART communications right. Reading pages 613 onwards, I understand that the value I should set for `USARTDIV` depends on the clock rate of AHB1 (since I am working with USART3, governed by the AHB1 clock).

Looking at pages 614 onwards, I see that the clock rate `f_PCLK` can take many different values (8MHz, 12Mhz, etc.). However, I cannot see anywhere where I can set the speed of that clock.

How can I measure/change/read the speak of the AHB1 clock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 83 of the reference manual has a clock tree diagram. This will help you see where the clocks come from.

The PCLK is a peripheral clock and will depend on the clock source and the prescaler values. The AHB, APB and other prescaler values are set in the system_stm32f2xx.c file.

Comment: Thanks! Do you understand what the line `__I uint8_t AHBPrescTable[16] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9};` exactly means?

Comment: It's an array that is used to set the SystemCoreClock variable. Search for both AHBPrescTable and SystemCoreClock and you should be able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Armandas, I know this is an ancient topic, but could you describe how AHBPrescTable is indexed, I'm finding the code impenetrable. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardWhitehead I don't get your question. What do you mean by "indexed"?